# There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to install rvm but getting this same error .I have read various pages but unable to resolve my error.I am following this [link](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)

I have given source

```
source /home/ankur/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

When I run this command

```
rvm install 2.4.0
```

I get this error.I am currently working on **ubuntu 14.04**

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/i386/ruby-2.4.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/aniket/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.4.0 - #downloading ruby-2.4.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
/home/aniket/.rvm/scripts/fetch: line 105: log: command not found
Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
/home/aniket/.rvm/scripts/fetch: line 105: log: command not found
Failed download
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Did you try one or more of the suggestions in the *Certificate Verification* section of the webpage mentioned in the error message?

Comment: As a side note: While the *log: command not found* seems to me a consequence of the certificate verification problem, it still should not occur, and it looks like a bug in the install script; but it also could mean that the installation of rvm is incomplete. Did you check line 105?

Comment: yeah i have resolved this issue now

Comment: Good to hear that. Maybe you could edit your posting to include a note, how you resolved it exactly - for the benefit of other users ahving a similar issue.

Comment: Ok I have resolved this post because where i work there was https connection blocked. So i have contacted system administrator to unblock it